# Como retiro certas linhas de um arquivo csv no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um arquivo em csv, que contem diversas linhas. Alguém sabe o que devo fazer para salvar em um novo documento, com algumas linhas especificas? Uma das colunas, 'yyyy', tem dados dos anos de 2015 a 2019. Gostaria de ficar apenas com os dados de 2018.

Abraços

Comment: Você poderia abrir um arquivo para leitura e outro para gravação, aí fazendo um `for` para ler linha por linha do arquivo de leitura seria só fazer um `if` e gravar no arquivo apenas se passar por esse `if`